# Can I extract the values using regex in a single regex string

Tags: regex

Any help will be appreciated. I have written a regex which fails in some edge cases. Not sure if there is a way to handle this.
I am trying to extract the values which having a 1.1 and 1.2 etc etc.
The regex I am using is
    **`"[1-9]\.[1-9]([^\s]+)"`** If i use it it extracts the first three values but the 4.1 which has a space, only part is extracted. If i use **`"[1-9]\.1.*[(XDX)]$"`** It starts to capture the whole line.

Currently I have written a logic which check for MR and splits it and puts in array which is very inefficient way to do.

Let me know if you can think of a better solution than this one.

```
GIBBERISH
1.1CDDAX/SXEVEN MR*XDX  2.1CDDAX/JEROME MR*XDX
3.1CDDAX/SIXM MR*XDX    4.1CDDAX AMX/SIXM MR*XDX
1  OXP EY 31SED W PK3  MEL/REDOOK DEOPRE 31SED21 XO XRXVEL DEF
EXPRESSA VERO IN IIS AETATIBUS, QUAE IAM CONFIRMATAE SUNT. ATQUI 
PERSPICUUM EST HOMINEM E CORPORE ANIMOQUE CONSTARE, 
CUM PRIMAE SINT ANIMI PARTES, SECUNDAE CORPORIS. TUM QUINTUS: 
EST PLANE, PISO, UT DICIS, INQUIT. BONA AUTEM CORPORIS HUIC SUNT, 
QUOD POSTERIUS POSUI, SIMILIORA. ILLA TAMEN SIMPLICIA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)[1-9]\.[1-9](.*?)(?=\s+MR\*XDX|$)
```

Or,

```
(?<!\S)[1-9]\.[1-9]((?:(?!\s+MR\*XDX).)+)
```

See this [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mlEWbo/2) or [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mlEWbo/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace should come right before the current location or start of string
- `[1-9]\.[1-9]` - a digit from `1` to `9`, then a `.`, and then again a digit from `1` to `9`
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s+MR\*XDX|$)` - `.*?` will stop matching before the first occurrence of

  - `\s+MR\*XDX` - 1+ whitespace and then `MR*XDX` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: Wow, you are genius !!! Thanks for extending my boundaries also. I had like whole lot of unnecessary codes just to do this. I do not any more words than looking at your masterpiece !!!